# Issue Implementing A* in C++ with Priority Queues

Tags: c++, priority-queue, a-star

I'm currently working on a homework assignment to implement A* for the sliding brick puzzle. I have previously implemented BFS and DFS for this puzzle, but an now having problems. I attempted to write my A* code by adapting the BFS code I already had working using a priority queue and Manhattan distance as the heuristic. In order to have the program open the node with the lowest f value (g+h), I had to override the operator for the priority queue, as it contains a defined structure. When I compile the code, no errors arise, but when I run it the program just crashed. My guess is that it is getting stuck in a loop somewhere. Maybe I implemented the operator override incorrectly. Can anyone help me figure out what is going wrong? I have pasted my code below.

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <vector>
#include <iostream>
#include <fstream>
#include <string>
#include <cstring>
#include <list>
#include <queue>
#include <set>
#include <stack>
#include <map>
#include <time.h>

using namespace std;

struct move //creates structure for a move containing a pice number and direction to move
{
    int piece;
    char direction;
};

struct parentmove
{
    vector< vector<int> > par;
    move mo;
};

struct position
{
    int row;
    int column;
};

struct node
{
    vector< vector<int> > par;
    vector< vector<int> > state;
    position pos;
    int g;
    int h;
    int f;
};

bool operator<(const node& a, const node& b)
{
    return a.f > b.f;
}

void SBP::Astar(vector <vector<int> > st)
{
    position goalpos = getposition(st, -1);
    node stnode;
    stnode.state = st;
    stnode.g = 0;
    position stpos = getposition(st, 2);
    stnode.h = abs(goalpos.row - stpos.row) + abs(goalpos.column - stpos.column);
    stnode.f = stnode.g + stnode.h;
    stnode.pos = stpos;
    list<move> allm;
    priority_queue< node > unexplored, explored;
    set< vector <vector<int> > > closedset; //contains explored states in a set, 
    map < vector <vector<int> >, parentmove > pathdict;
    allm = (*this).allmoves(st);
    list<move>::iterator it = allm.begin();
    for (int i = 0; i < allm.size(); i++)
    {
        move m;
        m.piece = (*it).piece;
        m.direction = (*it).direction;
        vector< vector<int> > newst = (*this).applyMove(st, m);
        newst = (*this).normalization(newst);
        node newnode;
        newnode.par = st;
        newnode.state = newst;
        newnode.g = 1;
        position newpos = getposition(newst, 2);
        newnode.h = abs(goalpos.row - newpos.row) + abs(goalpos.column - newpos.column);
        newnode.f = newnode.h + newnode.g;
        newnode.pos = newpos;
        unexplored.push(newnode);

        parentmove pm = { st,m };
        pathdict[newst] = pm;
        ++it;
    }
    explored.push(stnode);
    closedset.insert(st);
    while (!unexplored.empty())
    {
        node currentnode = unexplored.top();
        vector< vector<int> > currentst = currentnode.state;
        unexplored.pop();
        bool iscomplete = (*this).complete(currentst);
        if (iscomplete)
        {
            explored.push(currentnode);
            closedset.insert(currentst);
            list<move> path = (*this).constructpath(currentst, pathdict, st);
            (*this).display(currentst);
            printf("A* explored %i nodes\n", explored.size());
            printf("The length of the path solution is %i moves\n", path.size());
            return;
        }
        else
        {
            set< vector< vector<int> > >::iterator ite = closedset.find(currentst);
            if (ite == closedset.end()) //does not already exist in queue
            {
                list<move> possm;
                possm = (*this).allmoves(currentst);
                list<move>::iterator iter = possm.begin();
                for (int j = 0; j < possm.size(); j++)
                {
                    move m;
                    m.piece = (*iter).piece;
                    m.direction = (*iter).direction;
                    vector< vector<int> > newst = (*this).applyMove(currentst, m);
                    vector< vector<int> > normst = (*this).normalization(newst);;
                    node normnode;
                    normnode.state = normst;
                    normnode.par = currentst;
                    normnode.g = currentnode.g + 1;
                    position p = getposition(normst, 2);
                    normnode.h = abs(goalpos.row - p.row) + abs(goalpos.column - p.column);
                    normnode.f = normnode.g + normnode.h;
                    normnode.pos = p;
                    unexplored.push(normnode);
                    if (pathdict.find(normst) == pathdict.end())
                    {
                        parentmove pm = { currentst,m };
                        pathdict[normst] = pm;
                    }
                    ++iter;
                }
                explored.push(currentnode);
                closedset.insert(currentst);
            }
        }
    }

    return;
}
```

Comment: <humour>Should the C++ version of A* not be `std::unique_ptr<A>`?</humour>

Comment: This code does not compile. Is it an *excerpt* of a file you use?

Comment: On topic, if the program crashes or freezes, run it in the debugger that came with your development environment. On a crash, the debugger will halt and you can inspect the back trace to see where you are, how you got there, and some of the variables involved. More details can be printed as required. If the program freezes, pause the program and again take a look at the stack. step for a while so you can identify what loop the code is stuck in and why. If that doesn't help you figure it out, post the results of your investigation in with your question.

Comment: [mcve] highly recommended, but it doesn't sound like you are in a good position to create one without further investigation.

Comment: *When I compile the code, no errors arise, but when I run it the program just crashed* -- I wished posters would stop saying this..  A program compiling successfully only means that the program has no syntax errors.  It has no bearing on whether there are logical errors.

Comment: Is this intentional or is there a mismatch here: `bool operator<(const node& a, const node& b)
{
    return a.f > b.f;
}` ?

Comment: "when I run it the program just crashed". That's not very helpful. *Where* does it crash?